# Concatenate dates only return the day part

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have an excel where i would like to concatenate one string and one date.
The date is added as a number in the concatenated string, so i added text() function but it only returns the day correct, not the year and month.
How can i get the whole date as a string in my concatenated list?

=CONCAT(TEXT(I4;"yyyy-mm-dd");",";J4)

[image]

I tried with different formats on the cell:

[image]

Comment: Your formula should work, having just tried it exactly myself. Make sure your date is actually stored as a date and not as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is localised, so try:

```
=SAMMENKÆDNING(TEKST(I4;"åååå-mm-dd");",";J4)
```

Result:

[image]

Workaround:

```
=SAMMENKÆDNING(TEKST(ÅR(I4);"0000");TEKST(MÅNED(I4);"-00");TEKST(DAG(I4);"-00");",";J4)

' or:

=CONCAT(TEXT(YEAR(I4),"0000"),TEXT(MONTH(I4),"-00"),TEXT(DAY(I4),"-00"),",",J4)
```

Comment: Ah i see! When i tried this i got the year right but not the month (!) came out like 2023-00-07

Comment: You may have to fall back to concatenate the output from YEAR, MONTH, and DAY functions.

Comment: Is there are localization for the mm format?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this VBA code from a regular module. It should provide you with the relevant DMY codes for your locale.

Note that the codes returned will be Case Sensitive:

```
Sub International()
    With Application
        MsgBox "Year Code:" & vbTab & .International(xlYearCode) _
            & vbLf & "Month Code:" & vbTab & .International(xlMonthCode) _
            & vbLf & "Day Code:  " & vbTab & .International(xlDayCode)
    End With
        
End Sub
```